# design a big network only switches

Tags: wired-networking

i want design network of internet contain one Cisco router fiber optical and connect with 40 switches separate how can get a better topology.and what Disadvantage on it.
note: each switch will be in station far from another 7 to 15 mile

Comment: Sounds like a serious deployment plan. You should contact a professional network consultant.

Comment: Off topic. Try http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/, but please read http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic first

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to design a hub and spoke intranet network topology.  Each station switch (let's call these sites) should be configured as network segment. The sizing of each network segment will depend on the number of devices that will be connected: Use a class C network segmentation (255.255.255.0) for less than 256 devices, use a class B network segmentation(255.255.0.0) for less than 65,536 devices...and if you are building a giant network, use a class A network segmentation (255.0.0.0) for up to 16,777,216 devices on that station switch.

There are other consideration too for further segmentation with site, mainly bandwidth utilization or the use of virtual networks like in VMWare topology...but I can ramble for pages from this point onward. Suffice to say that the topology should be a hub and spoke design.